# removing a value from an array in php using unset

Tags: php

I have an array of question assignments and an array of questions. I want to remove the assigned ones from the questions array by iterating through the assigned questions and removing the id of those questions from the questions array.

That should leave me with an array of questions which are not assigned.

e.g

assigned_questions(1,2,3,4,5)

questions(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

should leave

questions(6,7,8,9,10)

so my assignments array contains a survey_questions_id so I'm doing a foreach and unsetting the id of the question in the questions array but I do not get an array with the questions that are assigned removed,

```
    public function remove_assigned_questions($questions, $survey_id) {

        $assignments = $this->db->rs( T_SURVEY_QUESTION_ASSIGNMENTS, NULL, (T_SURVEYS . TC_ID_SUFFIX .'=' . $survey_id) );


        foreach($assignments as $assignment) {

           unset($questions[$assignment[T_SURVEY_QUESTIONS . TC_ID_SUFFIX]]);


        }

        return $questions;

    }
```

my questions array looks like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["survey_question"]=>
    string(13) "Some question"
    ["survey_question_types_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["required"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["survey_question"]=>
    string(17) "One more question"
    ["survey_question_types_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["required"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["survey_question"]=>
    string(21) "Just another question"
    ["survey_question_types_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["required"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Any idea why it just isn't removing the questions with the assignment[T_SURVEY_QUESTIONS . TC_ID_SUFFIX]

Here are the values of assignments and following that, the foreach loop values of assignment[T_SURVEY_QUESTIONS . TC_ID_SUFFIX]

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["surveys_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["survey_questions_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["surveys_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["survey_questions_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
string(1) "1"
string(1) "2"
```

When the program runs, it seems to remove question with ids 2 and 3 and leaves me with 1

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["survey_question"]=>
    string(13) "Some question"
    ["survey_question_types_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["required"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

which is incorrect as 1 is assigned

Comment: We'd need the values of `$assignments`, `T_SURVEY_QUESTIONS` and `TC_ID_SUFFIX` to be able to say anything…

Comment: just added those

Comment: You're testing the return value of `remove_assigned_questions`, or do you expect the `$questions` input argument to be modified in place?

Comment: I hoping $questions will be returned by remove_assigned_questions and have the id's of the assigned questions removed

Comment: You understand that you're unsetting *array offsets*, not unsetting questions by their `id`?!

Comment: no - can you explain?

Comment: You're doing `unset($questions['1'])`, which removes the second question in the array (index `[1]`); not the question with `["id"] => "1"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166041/discussion-between-rich-and-deceze).

Answer (score 0):

I sussed it thanks to @deceze pointing out what I was doing wrong, I needed to find the key of the question array in questions with the value of question_id which was assigned and then remove that array key

```
public function remove_assigned_questions($questions, $survey_id) {

    $assignments = $this->db->rs( T_SURVEY_QUESTION_ASSIGNMENTS, NULL, (T_SURVEYS . TC_ID_SUFFIX . '=' . $survey_id) );
    $ids = array_column($questions, TC_ID);

    foreach($assignments as $assignment) {

        if( $key = array_search( $assignment[T_SURVEY_QUESTIONS . TC_ID_SUFFIX], $ids ) );
        unset($questions[$key]);

    }

    return $questions;

}
```

Sorted ;)